# Pycharm shows interpretor version of 2.7 but I have downloaded 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pycharm

I'm a complete newbie trying to use pycharm with python but my interpretor shows a version of 2.7 when i have installed 3.6. Totally confused and need help!

On pycharm I do the following steps:

Preferences > Python Console > Python Interpretor

I only see Python 2.7.8 (/Library/Framework/....) and beneath this I see options beginning with (/Library/Framework.... ) <-- some of these end in bin/python3.6

I am not sure how to configure Pycharm to use the new version of Python. Being a complete newbie I am really confused as to what to do? and whether changing this makes any difference.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install python 3.6?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html ?

Comment: Can you try to find which Python version are installed in your computer?Type from command line 
`~ $which python`. With this you may find the installed path of your interpreter. Then you can select the interpreter in Pycharm with this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter` (it should take you there automatically as soon as you open Settings) and select the version you want to use from the drop-menu. If it is not there, try restarting PyCharm (if it was active whilst the Python 3 installation) - else, it probably means you didn't install Python 3 properly.

Comment: @priyesh091 If there was an answer which helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know where is python installed with the command `which python` (in some cases this command output you the location of **python-2.7**, but you can try this other command for **python-3.x** `which python3`) if you are in debian the output it gonna see like this `/usr/bin/python` this is the folder where all (usually) all your python version

Second,Enter to Pycharm: `settings/Project:#name of your Project#/Project interpreter` In the top of this window you can see a option called `project interpreter` it actually have a location of the actual python that pycharm run, yo change it use this example:

```
/usr/bin/pythonX
```

Where `X` is the version of python.

in my case:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6
```